# How to extract angular raw code from argument in directive and render it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Not sure, how to describe this question more. So there is simple code and jsfiddle

html

```
<div>
  <span format="the value is: {{value||'no-val'}}" value="100" my-test></span>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
App.directive('myTest', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
          format: '@'
      },
      template: "<span>{{format}}</span>",
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          $scope.value = attrs.value
     }
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VhvEy/2

My expectation `<span>the value is: 100</span>`

Reality `<span>the value is: no-val</span>`

Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are interpolating `value` it needs to refer to a scoped property in a controller.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/KvX38/).

So, you need to add a controller:

```
App.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.value = 100;
})
```

and wire up the controller with `ng-controller`:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

The `value` attribute on the `<span>` will not automatically be bound to the angular scope.

**EDIT:**

If you really want to interpolate the template in the directive, you can override the `compile` function inside the directive:

```
App.directive('myTest', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            value: '@'
        },
        compile:function(element, attrs) {

            var strTemplate = "<span>{{" + attrs.format +"}}</span>";
            element.replaceWith(strTemplate);
        }
    }
})
```

To do this, don't interpolate in the html, just send through the text that you want to interpolate in the directive:

```
<span format="value || 'no-val'" value="100" my-test></span>
```

Here is an [adapted working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/Zbdrs/) that shows this in action.

Comment: But, how do i load value from attribute in my-test directive element?

Comment: Which attribute's value?  Right now, you are defining `format` attribute with `@`, so this will pass the value of `format` into the directive's scope.

Comment: Maybe I am doing this completely wrong. I want attribute `format` to defined how attribute `value` should be formatted in my directive. Both attributes are on directive element level.

Comment: @Schovi check out my edit, it shows how to compile the template in the directive.